# google maps location service

Tags: browser, google-maps, location

How does Google Maps find out my location on my Desktop/Laptop ?

Google says it might use my IP or Wifi data to determine my location.

But how can a Browser read my Wifi data ? Is it really possible ? Can it read my Router's MAC ID ? Signal Strength ? How ? how ? how ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not reading the wifi data like that from your computer.  What they mean is that your wifi provider (if you're using a public provider) may provide data on the location associated with someone connected to a given IP address.

Answer (score 0):

It matches your IP address, not your router IP, but your cable modem address to a list of registered IPs.  This published IP mapping has a physical address, and then geocodes your address.